# recharts img not rendering in customized dot

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, reactstrap, recharts

I want to render images from a URL as dots for a line chart.

**I added the "CharacterDot" like its shown in the docs, but it doesn't render anything. If I use the same code but use an SVG instead of an image (exactly how its used in the docs) it works.**

This is an example from the docs. https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/9y9zrpjp/

```
class CharacterDot extends Component {
    render() {
        const { cx, cy } = this.props;

        return (
            <img cx={cx - 15} cy={cy - 15} width={30} height={30} src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'/>
        );
    }
}

<ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height={400}>
    <LineChart data={data2} margin={{ right: 50, left: 50 }}>
        <Tooltip />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="value" stroke="black" strokeWidth="3px" dot={<CharacterDot />} />
    </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `isAnimationActive` flag for Line component

```
<Line type='monotone'
    dataKey='value'
    stroke="black"
    isAnimationActive={false}
    dot={<CharacterDot />} />
```